# I wrote a python script to dedupe a csv and I think it's 90% working. Could really use some help troubleshooting one issue

Tags: python, csv

The code is supposed to find duplicates by comparing FirstName, LastName, and Email. All Duplicates should be written to the Dupes.csv file, and all Uniques should be written to Deduplicated.csv, but this is currently not happening..

Example:

If row A shows up in Orginal.csv 10 times, the code writes A1 to deduplicated.csv, and it writes A2 - A10 to dupes.csv.

This is incorrect. A1-A10 should ALL be written to the dupes.csv file, leaving only unique rows in deduplicated.csv.

Another strange behavior is that A2-A10 are all getting written to dupes.csv TWICE!

I would really appreciate any and all feedback as this is my first professional python script and I'm feeling pretty disheartened.

Here is my code:

```
import csv

def read_csv(filename):
    the_file = open(filename, 'r', encoding='latin1')
    the_reader = csv.reader(the_file, dialect='excel')
    table = []
    #As long as the table row has values we will add it to the table
    for row in the_reader:
        if len(row) > 0:
            table.append(tuple(row))
    the_file.close()
    return table


def create_file(table, filename):
    join_file = open(filename, 'w+', encoding='latin1')
    for row in table:
        line = ""
        #build up the new row - don't comma on last item so add last item separate
        for i in range(len(row)-1):
            line += row[i] + ","
        line += row[-1]
        #adds the string to the new file
        join_file.write(line+'\n')
    join_file.close()


def main():
    original = read_csv('Contact.csv')

    print('finished read')
    #hold duplicate values
    dupes = []
    #holds all of the values without duplicates
    dedup = set()
    #pairs to know if we have seen a match before
    pairs = set()
    for row in original:
        #if row in dupes:
            #dupes.append(row)
        if (row[4],row[5],row[19]) in pairs:
            dupes.append(row)
        else:
            pairs.add((row[4],row[5],row[19]))
            dedup.add(row)

    print('finished first parse')
    #go through and add in one more of each duplicate
    seen = set()
    for row in dupes:
        if row in seen:
            continue
        else:
            dupes.append(row)
            seen.add(row)

    print ('writing files')
    create_file(dupes, 'duplicate_leads.csv')
    create_file(dedup, 'deduplicated_leads.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Not being facetious here, but asking a legit question. Why are you going to the trouble to write a script to do this for you when all you have to do is open the CSV in Google docs or MS Excel and choose the remove duplicates option.

Comment: @Korgrue there'es plenty of reasons why you might not want to rely on manual intervention to normalize a file, for example it is an input to a batch or scheduled job or other repeated process

Comment: @Korgrue why would you prepare your own food if you can buy it already prepared anyway ?

Comment: Maybe not much less facetious, but if you are dealing with csv, why not use pandas. rather than roll your own processing

Comment: You need to count occurrences of each row before you're checking whether it exists e.g., in `pairs`. The first call to `if (row[4],row[5],row[19]) in pairs` will always return `False`, for example.

Comment: +1 for pandas. Reading CSVs is implemented really efficient due to its parser implemented in C. It's more convenient and robust in combination with the "duplicated" method of dataframes (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) that let you create a mask for the duplicated values that you can then write to a seperate file

Comment: It will require 2 passes - first count the number of occurrences for each row, and then write into the appropriate file (if count=1 dedup, and if count>1 dupes)

Comment: @David Zemens Yeah, that is why I am asking. It may or may not be something he has to write a script for, so I am simply inquiring so I can provide the best answer I can to him. Often code is the best solution, but sometimes it is not.

Comment: @Korgrue Excel will remove the duplicates, but my client doesn't want to remove them, they want to isolate them so that they can manually review and merge where appropriate. Good question though!

Comment: @David Fair enough. Totally understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the pandas module for this, it will be extremely fast, and much easier than rolling your own.

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.read_csv('Contact.csv')

duplicates = x.duplicated(['row4', 'row5', 'row19'], keep = False) 
#use the names of the columns you want to check

x[duplicates].to_csv('duplicates.csv') #write duplicates

x[~duplicates].to_csv('uniques.csv') #write uniques
```

Comment: Is that code all there is to it? If so, that's amazing. Giving it a try..

Comment: I'm getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'.

Comment: nevermind, I got the module installed. (not used to having to pip install libraries)